# Communicate w/ Javascript running in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe, same-origin-policy

I'm currently working on an application that uses the Phonegap/Cordova framework to display an online and an offline version of a website. If you're not familiar w/ this framework, it offers a simple way of creating multi-platform applications by displaying local files in a full-screen webview.

When launching the application, the Javascript integrated in the local files of the application detects if Internet access if available, and redirects the user to either another local webpage containing a full-screen iFrame of the live website, or a reduced offline version of the website (contained in the local files of the app) if no Internet connection is detected.

I would like to detect when the user logs in using the various forms on the website (being displayed inside the iFrame), but I have no way of knowing which page the user is on, or interact w/ the website content at all because of the same-origin policy.

Would it be possible though to make the Javascript from the local page (which contains the iFrame) interact w/ the Javascript from the remote page (which is being displayed in the iFrame)? This way, I would be able to obtain the login information, and save it for later use (obviously not w/o using a token system), but also it would help for another planned feature (trigger the guidance system).

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this? If it is in fact the same origin should be no different than a standard page. Not sure if you would be able to call functions or not either, as I have never tried that.

Comment: @Adjit Yes, I've tried it. It is precisely NOT the same origin, that's why I can't access either the URL nor the content of the iFrame from the local page. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Well if it is not the same origin, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: if you control the iframed page's JS, then use `top.postMessage` to push events/data

Answer (score 0):

Look into HTML5 communication, it's pretty simple and sounds like it fits your needs

http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=109

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to take a look at it right now and report back w/ the results.

Comment: @NeatMonster By the way, h5 communication works across origins